# cannot read sqlite database , using entity framework in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

After referring to almost every question posted related to this issue. I am not able to find a solution for this problem.

I followed all the steps mentioned.
1)Download package from sqlite.org
2)install packages from nuget

Still sqlite does not appear in data source list for entity model wizard.

my app.config looks like this.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.Linq, Version=1.0.98.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />  </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  
</configuration>
```

I have tried almost anything but failed to get the basic steps required to connect to sqlite using entity framework and then read the data base.

I have created the database using DB Browser for sqlite, which is accessible through simple ADO.NET methods.

Once sqlite showed under data sources but then. provider errors were there.
such as

> No-Entity-Framework-provider-found-for-the-ADO-NET

Can someone please help me with the complete set of steps start from setting up environment till performing operations on sqlite dataase in visual studio 2013, .NET 4.5.1 , wpf, mvvm.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see you have a connection factory, but no connection string in your config file, is the connection string in your code somewhere?

Comment: connection string was there.then i removed it and tried to add the database again. which did not happened.

Answer (score 0):

try following the details in this link

[using sqllite with EF](http://erikej.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/using-sqlite-with-entity-framework-6.html)

grab the setup files, which are referenced in the wiki that there is a link to

[setup files which should register everything for you](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Ok, so going through the setup of the bundle for .Net, which registered the DLL's and works a treat, so you should go through the setup and should work for you

Comment: i have tried this as well. but again i cannot see sqlite as data source in entity model wizard.

Comment: have you got the sqllite client installed?

Comment: can you specify about this sqlclient...because I installed everything mentioned over the net for SQLite.

Comment: what specifically did you install, as it seems that you are missing some assemblies in order to find it

Comment: i installed SQLite DLLs from the website mentioned  eerywhere....version is 1.0.98.0.Then i installed EF6 package from visual studio.I have also trying installing it from visual studio only...the complete x86 package. still it did not work...

Comment: Did you grab the setup files or just the dlls? https://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.95.0/sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x64-2013-1.0.96.0.exe

Comment: I have edited my answer, to send you to the wiki that has the setup files youll need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88610/discussion-between-simon-price-and-neha).